# C++: Explicit vs Implicit Default Initialization

Tags: c++, class, c++11, initialization

I was told that implicit default initialization of a member variable is better than explicit default initialization.

Below in `Widget1` the private member `i` is default initialized when the constructor is called. But in `Widget2`, when the constructor is called, `i` is also default initialized.

```
class Widget1 {
public:
  Widget1() : i() {}
private:
  int i;
}

class Widget2 {
public:
  Widget2() {}
private:
  int i;
}
```

The questions I have are:

1. What's the difference between the initialization in both cases?
2. Does this change if the member variable is more complicated than simple POD?
3. In general, is one method preferred over the other?
4. Are there differences between this behavior in C++03 and C++11

Comment: "Default initialization" is what happens when no initializer is specified. In your class `Widget1`, `i` is *not* default initialized, it is *value initialized* since you gave it an empty initializer `()`. The `i` in `Widget2` *is* default initialized, since there is no initializer specified. Of course, default initialization for fundamental types does nothing leaving the value unspecified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the second case, i is not initialized, it  will end up with arbitrary values, it depends on the compiler, and also compiler options. On Windows with visual studio, if compiled with release, i will be a arbitrary value.

So the first is preferred.

if 'i' is a not POD type,  by default, its default constructor will be called.

Comment: Better arbitrary than random. And no difference for different standard versions.

Comment: @Deduplicator modified. Thanks!

Comment: @Casey, sorry, it should be arbitrary too. :)